# Why is Tomcat 9 serving same SSL certificate for two different domains that are configured separately?

Tags: ssl, tomcat, servlets, lets-encrypt

I have one Linux server where I run three different websites

Server.xml looks like the following

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="443" />

<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="1000" SSLEnabled="true" defaultSSLHostConfigName="sub1.domain1.info">
        <SSLHostConfig hostName="sub1.domain1.info">
            <Certificate certificateFile="conf/app1/cert.pem" certificateKeyFile="conf/app1/privkey.pem" certificateChainFile="conf/app1/chain.pem"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
        <SSLHostConfig hostName="www.domain2.com/">
            <Certificate certificateFile="conf/app2/cert.pem" certificateKeyFile="conf/app2/privkey.pem" certificateChainFile="conf/app2/chain.pem"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
        <SSLHostConfig hostName="domain3.ac.in">
            <Certificate certificateFile="conf/app3/cert.pem" certificateKeyFile="conf/app3/privkey.pem" certificateChainFile="conf/app3/chain.pem"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
        <SSLHostConfig hostName="*.domain3.ac.in">
            <Certificate certificateFile="conf/app2/cert.pem" certificateKeyFile="conf/app2/privkey.pem" certificateChainFile="conf/app2/chain.pem"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>

<Host name="sub1.domain1.info" appBase="/home/applocation" unpackWARs="false" deployXML="false">
        <Alias>sub1.domain1.info</Alias>
          <Context path="" reloadable="true" docBase="/home/applocation" debug="1"/>
        <Context docBase="/home/filepath" path="/pattern"/>
       </Host>

<Host name="domain2.com" appBase="/home/app2path" unpackWARs="false" deployXML="false">
          <Alias>www.domain2.com</Alias>
          <Context path="" reloadable="true" docBase="/home/app2path" debug="1"/>
</Host>
<Host name="domain3.ac.in" appBase="/home/app3path" unpackWARs="false" deployXML="false">
          <Alias>www.domain3.ac.in</Alias>
          <Context path="" reloadable="true" docBase="/home/app3path" debug="1"/>
</Host>
```

Certificates generated using certbot

```
certbot certonly --standalone -d domainName
```

For some reason, when domain2.com is loaded on the browser, it says certificate is not valid. When I check details of the certificate, it carried the details of sub1.domain1.info's certificate (issued to sub1.domain1.info).

I am confused because, it worked for domain3.ac.in
Certificates were first generated for sub1.domain1.com followed by domain3.ac.in and at last [www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com) (at least 3 times generated for this domain now).

One thing I noted is that I get one warning while generating certificate for [www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com) that says something like "this might not work" but got generated anyway.

Also I am new to SSL with Tomcat, so please suggest any other necessary changes also.

Comment: Check the data in the files (e.g. with `openssl x509 -in <filename> -noout -text`). What browser do you use? If it does not support or use [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) (unlikely these days), the first certificate configured will be served.

Comment: I am latest Google Chrome. I have tried to configure another domain from scratch, still no luck :(